# Error when query run Mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$query = "INSERT INTO add (`datetime`,`category`,`subcategory`,`selectapet`,`breed`,`title`,`description`,`inthisad`,`sizeatmaturity`,`age`,`gender`,`fprice`,`tprice`,`picture`,`email`,`name`,`mobile`,`phone`,`address`,`city`,`state`,`country`) VALUES (NOW(),'$category', '$subcategory', '$selectapet','$breed','$title','$description','$inthisad','$sizeatmaturity','$age','$gender','$fromprice','$toprice','$picture','$email','$name','$mobile','$phone','$address','$city','$state','$country')";

       $result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("error when query run") ;
```

Error is    "error when query run" is what i m getting have provided all input. datetime is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and i m using NOW() for it

Comment: @Peder Something with little Bobby Tables. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: `NOW()` should not be in quotes, you are passing the string and not calling the function. Although is the default is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` you can either omit the column or pass `NULL` and it will work the same way.

Comment: Change `$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("error when query run") ;` to `$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));` and tell us what you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD (your table name) is a reserved word and should be backticked with ` in the same way as your column names

Answer (score 1):

I can see at least 2 issues straight away here.

- `INSERT INTO add` - ADD is a reserved word, you must quote it.
- `'NOW()'` - needs to be unquoted.

**Edit:**

I see you edited your question and removed the quotes from `NOW()` already. Leaving it in the answer though as it *was* a problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should use NOW() function without quotes this way:

```
`country`) VALUES (NOW(),'$category',
```

also add quotes for the table name:

```
INSERT INTO `add` ( ...
```

Comment: what is the definition of your table? copy past it here. 
also can you let us know the exact error that mysql returns?

Answer (score 0):

Remvoe single quote from NOW() function, Because its a function not a string ?

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your query . add is a keyword you need to put quotes around it. Change your query to:

```
$query ="INSERT INTO `add` (`datetime`,`category`,`subcategory`,`selectapet`,`breed`,`title`,`description`,`inthisad`,`sizeatmaturity`,`age`,`gender`,`fprice`,`tprice`,`picture`,`email`,`name`,`mobile`,`phone`,`address`,`city`,`state`,`country`) VALUES ( NOW(),'$category', '$subcategory', '$selectapet','$breed','$title','$description','$inthisad','$sizeatmaturity','$age','$gender','$fromprice','$toprice','$picture','$email','$name','$mobile','$phone','$address','$city','$state','$country')";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("error when query run") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote from NOW() function ie change 'NOW()' to NOW()